# How to make an event inside an Iframe work with the handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want that when you hover over the part that is inside the iframe/ hyperlink the animation will work. Currently nothing happens. I have made the width of the div on my  [website](http://tragicclothing.co.uk/deleteeee.html) slightly wider so you can see what the mouse over event (action) should do.

Html (for video):

```
<div id="box3" onmouseout="$('#box3').stop().animate({boxShadow: '10px 10px 15px', top: 0}, 'fast')"
    onmousemove="$('#box3').stop().animate({boxShadow: '3px 3px 3px', top: 3}, 'fast')" style="top: 0px;
width: 710px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px 0px rgb(102, 102, 102);">
<iframe width="700" height="525" id="under" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LRo-L9zYf-M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

I tried putting another div in front of the iframe using css  and z-index but that didn't work

Css:

```
#under {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
```

}

```
#box3 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

}

```
#box3 {
z-index: 10;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any experience with Javascript?

Comment: A tiny bit but for the sake of it pretend that I do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the contents of an iFrame from a different domain using Javascript. All modern browsers have that as a security feature to keep you from stealing Credit Card information. As far as I know there is no way around this.

Comment: Could I use something other than an iframe to play a youtube video or vimeo video?